# How can I block low voltages (around 40 mV) but allow higher voltages?

Tags: dc, wiring, 12v

So, I'm wiring up some LEDs on a vehicle and am running into an issue where a wire that is supposed to be unpowered when switched off is putting out a constant 0.04 Volts. Is there a way to create a "high-pass filter" to eliminate that voltage to the lights until switched on fully?

Comment: a high-pass filter would, due to the very definition of "high-pass", eliminate *all* DC, including what you plan to use to power your LEDs. So, that's not what you want. Maybe you want to add a switch with a specific turn-on voltage? (Possibly: also hysteresis)

Comment: Does 0.04 volts illuminate your LEDs?

Comment: Try measuring the unpowered wire with respect to other 0 V reference points on the vehicle. I'll wager that your 40 mV is just an artefact of where you're measuring it against, and that you're running some current somewhere which is causing that small drop in some earth wiring.

Comment: What sort of problem is that 0.04 V causing you? I can't think of any normal situation in which 0.04 V is a problem, which makes me think that either you don't have a problem at all, or you have some kind of unusual situation which may require an unusual solution.

Answer (score 4):

If it's controlled by a computer, it's possible there's a small (on average) current flowing that is intended to check for filament failure. The peak voltage may be far higher than 40mV but your multimeter may read that because its pulsed, for example. Since 40mV would not cause any issue with LEDs (which require more than 1V to illuminate), that's possibly the case here.

A common approach to that (sadly) when retro-fitting LED lights is to put a power-wasting resistor in parallel with the LED, particularly with turn signals where the main issue that the flasher module is expecting a relatively high current. They are also used to prevent error codes and dash indicators from being activated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that voltage is real a forward inline diode will stop anything unless it goes over (say) 0.6V for silicon.

Answer (score 0):

If the LED is still glowing at such a low voltage, the current will be tiny, and the LED's impedance at such currents will be very high. Try placing 10kΩ resistance in parallel with the LED, as a "preferred" path for that current.

Failing that, a low-voltage cut off system that should work is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRcs7w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First try without R2 (it's the same trick I suggested above), but if the LED still glows, then include R2. The transistor is switched on only for inputs that exceed its \$V_{GS(ON)}\$ parameter (about 3V for the model shown):

[image]

If current for the LED in question is less than 300mA or so, then you don't need such a beefy MOSFET, and any small P-channel enhanced mode device, like the BSS84, should do.

I don't think this is a very "automotive grade" solution, as the power voltage can spike dramatically, and I make no promises about how safe the MOSFET is under such stresses. I have protected the gate with D1, though. If you omit D1, you risk killing the MOSFET with the kind of severe input voltage transients expected in a vehicle's electrical system.